# ASP.NET Core MVC : edit user, problem with passing data from view to controller ,identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

I've pasted below main parts of code that I have problem with. I use ASP.NET Core MVC with Identity. I want to edit user data by passing new ones through Input from `Index.cshtml` to `Process` method in `OrderController`. The problem is that in the `Process` method, `Input.FirstName`, `Input.SureName` etc. are null.

OrderController:

```
public class OrderController : Controller
{
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
        private string strCart = "Cart";
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        public List<Cart> articlesCart = new List<Cart>();

        public OrderController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
            _userManager = userManager;
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            completeList();
            return View();
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public InputModel Input { get; set; } = new InputModel();

        public class InputModel
        {
            [Required]
            [Display(Name = "Imię")]
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            [Required]
            [Display(Name = "Nazwisko")]
            public string SureName { get; set; }
            [Required]
            [Display(Name = "Ulica")]
            public string Address { get; set; }
            [Required]
            [Display(Name = "Miasto")]
            public string City { get; set; }
            [Required]
            [Display(Name = "Kod pocztowy")]
            public string PostCode { get; set; }
            [Required]
            public string PaymentMethod { get; set; }
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Process()
        {
            var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);   

            if (user != null)
            {
                user.FirstName = Input.FirstName;
                user.SureName = Input.SureName;
                user.Address = Input.Address;
                user.City = Input.City;
                user.PostCode = Input.PostCode;

                await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);

                completeList();

                foreach (var cookie in Request.Cookies.Keys)
                {
                    Response.Cookies.Delete(cookie);
                }

                return View();
            }

            return NotFound();
        }
}
```

Index.cshtml:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@using ShopIdentity.Controllers
@using ShopIdentity.Data
@model OrderController

@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto">
        <form id="registerForm"  method="post">
            
            <hr />
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-floating">
                <input asp-for="Input.FirstName" class="form-control" aria-required="true" />
                <label asp-for="Input.FirstName"></label>
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="form-floating">
                <input asp-for="Input.SureName" class="form-control" aria-required="true" />
                <label asp-for="Input.SureName"></label>
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.SureName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="form-floating">
                <input asp-for="Input.Address" class="form-control" aria-required="true" />
                <label asp-for="Input.Address"></label>
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.Address" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="form-floating">
                <input asp-for="Input.City" class="form-control" aria-required="true" />
                <label asp-for="Input.City"></label>
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.City" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="form-floating">
                <input asp-for="Input.PostCode" class="form-control" aria-required="true"/>
                <label asp-for="Input.PostCode"></label>
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.PostCode" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <br />
             
            <div class="form-floating">             
                <select style="width: 200px" asp-for="Input.PaymentMethod" id="Input.PaymentMethod" class ="dropdown" name="Input.PaymentMethod">
                    <option selected hidden>Metoda płatności</option>
                    <option value="Gotówka">Gotówka</option>
                    <option value="PayPal">PayPal</option>
                    <option value="Karta płatnicza">Karta płatnicza</option>
                    <option value="Przelew bankowy">Przelew bankowy</option>
                </select>
                
            </div>
            <br />
            <a asp-action="Proces" id="registerForm" asp-controller="Order" class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary">Złóż zamówienie</a>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-2">
       
    </div>
</div>


@section Scripts {
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Process method:

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Proces([Bind("FirstName,SureName,Address,City,PostCode,PaymentMethod")] InputModel Input)
        {
           the same code
        }
```

Index.cshtml:

```
@model ShopIdentity.Models.InputModel
...
<div class="form-floating">
                <input asp-for="FirstName" class="form-control" aria-required="true" />
                <label asp-for="FirstName"></label>
                <span asp-validation-for="FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
...
```

Comment: Why are you using the BindProperty syntax? It is more common in MVC to have a model class specified in the view and then pass the model to the Process action, which gets bound automatically. I haven't tried the Razor pages syntax in a controller before.

Comment: @LukeBriner ok. So first I will create new model class InputModel adn then actually what should I do?

Comment: Once you have bound the model to the view, check out the code about handling the post action (about half way down here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/controller-methods-views?view=aspnetcore-6.0) You can just pass the model as a parameter or can optionally restrict which properties are expected on this action with Bind()

Comment: @LukeBriner I have updated my post and added what you mentioned. Once I submit the form I get 405 error

Comment: Your Process action should be marked as HttpPost, not HttpGet

Comment: @LukeBriner Yes,check Update section (bottom of my post)

Comment: You spelled Process with 1 "s" what error are you getting now?

Comment: @LukeBriner I have just found out that form+button supports [HttpPost] and <a>+form supports [HttpGet]. So I have changed it. I still get error but another one: **A database operation failed while processing the request.
SqlException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Address', table 'MyDbIdentity.dbo.AspNetUsers'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails. The statement has been terminated.**

Comment: Good luck, it sounds like you need to spend more time learning the basics. SO is for answering specific questions not teaching people for free!

Comment: @LukeBriner is correct, you need to take a step back and learn the MVC framework. Also, you are mixing MVC  and Razor Pages, please learn the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try refactoring your `asp-for` statements to only use the property name (e.g., change `asp-for="Input.PostCode"` to `asp-for="PostCode"`). Your model binding is looking for the property PostCode and not finding it because your request data has Input.PostCode as the property name.

Comment: I have just changed it. Unfortunately I get error 415 GET:https://localhost:7115/Order/Process

Comment: What should I type in @model? Because In my controller I have "Input" object of InputModel class. Inside my controller there is also InputModel inside class

Answer (score 0):

Try to use button rather than `<a>` tag to submit form:

```
<form id="registerForm"  method="post" asp-action="Proces" asp-controller="Order">
            
           ...
            <input type="submit" value="Złóż zamówienie"/>
        </form>
```